# Recover Windows' System Image on machine with only USB-3 ports

Tags: windows-7, usb-3, system-restore

I am trying to recover a Windows-7 System Image on to a laptop that only has USB-3 external ports, but can't as once I boot into the System Recovery disc, these ports all stop functioning.

I believe this is because the System Recovery does not include USB-3 drivers, as the laptop's internal USB-2 devices continue to work.

Is there some way to recover this System Image?

Comment: https://www.cybernetman.com/kb/article/how-to-slipstream-usb-3-0-drivers-into-windows-7-installation-media

Comment: Thank you @Moab. Unfortunately, this article discusses a fresh install of Windows, and I was not able to get it to work on a system-image recovery.

Comment: Yeah but if you make the disc, boot from it and do a repair install.

Comment: @Moab I had tried it with the system recovery disc, but the injection tool gave a "not found" type error. I assumed this is because it expected an actual Windows-7 install disc, not just a system recovery disc. I don't have a Windows-7 installation disc as the system image was from an OEM install. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Moab I managed to get hold of a Windows-7 disc and your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you, my system image is recovered. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your hands on a Windows 7 Installation disc that has SP1, then [slipstream](https://www.cybernetman.com/kb/article/how-to-slipstream-usb-3-0-drivers-into-windows-7-installation-media) the necessary usb 3.0 drivers into it.

Now boot from it and do a repair.